# Add prefix to each element list in R

Tags: r, list, data.table, tidyverse

I have a many csv files which I read using lapply & vroom package (it has 18 files with millions of rows in each files)

```
library(vroom)
filelist <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv")
```

dput(filelist)

```
c("UPW_119_1.csv", "UPW_119_2.csv", "UPW_119_3.csv")

files <- lapply(filelist, FUN=vroom)
```

Assuming below is how my list looks like :

```
files <- list(no1= c("1","2","3","4","5"), no2= c(1:3),no3 = c("190301010141","190301010141","190301010143","19030101014","190301010145"))
```

I want to add "91" prefix to each element in my list followed by the file name which they were part of in filelist

I tried something like this but its not right

```
mytry :
files2 <- paste0("91", files, fileslist[i]) #Adding file name
```

Required output

```
## List of 3
##  $ f1  : int [1:5] 911_UPW_119_1 912_UPW_119_1 913_UPW_119_1 914_UPW_119_1 915_UPW_119_1
##  $ no2: int [1:3] 911_UPW_119_2 912_UPW_119_2 913_UPW_119_2 
##  $ no3: int [1:5] "9190301010141_UPW_119_3","91190301010141_UPW_119_3","91190301010143_UPW_119_3","9119030101014_UPW_119_3","91190301010145_UPW_119_3")
```

I then want to write these csv files

So in a gist, read 18 csv files, do the modificaiton as above, add "91" (static) & file name (dynamic) then write 18 csv files

I have research SO a lot, tried lapply & list function etc but no help!

Comment: I will surely try this, is there a speedy/memory efficient way as well ? Since there are 18 files and with million of rows in each. This looks very slow way to execute same

Answer (score 1):

You can use lapply:

```
filelist <- c("UPW_119_1.csv", "UPW_119_2.csv", "UPW_119_3.csv")
files <- list(no1= c("1","2","3","4","5"), no2= c(1:3),no3 = c("190301010141","190301010141","190301010143","19030101014","190301010145"))

lapply(1:length(files), function(k) paste(91, files[[k]], sub(".csv", "", filelist[[k]], fixed = TRUE), sep = "_"))
```

It is vectorized in `lapply` so it is quite efficient

Comment: I get a strange output when I run this instead of 91 being prefixed in front of all elements, it gets done something like this "91c(7409476775, 8393990218, xxx) & similar with the suffix part. They should be attached to each element, not sure what this results

Comment: Second point, the end of list element looks like (xxx 8954911746)UPW_119_1.csv_") . I do not want .csv in the suffix in each element as well

Comment: Hi I still get file in this format: "91_c(7409476775,xxx,xxx)_UPW_119_1" I wanted 91 & suffix part after every number

Comment: I see your sample output & input works great but sadly I dont get same results on actual data

Comment: @Priyanka please check `dput` of `filelist` and `files`. We should not be far from your real needs.